# Angularjs combo box key value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using Angularjs and I have a dropdown box that lists several items. If the item the user needs is not in the list I need to allow the user to enter the data. Is this possible? How would I do it?

Comment: take a look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/r36vF/)**

**html**

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
    <fieldset ng-controller="FirstCtrl">
        <select ng-options="p.name for p in people" ng-model="selectedPerson"></select>

        <br>
            Name:<input type="text" ng-model="name"/>
            <button ng-click="add(name)">Add</button>
    </fieldset>
</div>
```

**script**

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);
myapp.controller('FirstCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.people = [{
        name: 'John'
    }, {
        name: 'Rocky'
    }, {
        name: 'John'
    }, {
        name: 'Ben'
    }];

    $scope.add = function(value)
    {
        var obj= {};
        obj.name = value;        
        $scope.people.push(obj); 
        $scope.name = '';
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want something like a tagging widget. Maybe looking at [angular-tags](http://decipherinc.github.io/angular-tags/) you can accomplish what you want

Comment: No, I need a combobox where I can key in a value or select one from the dropdown list